# jQuery closest TR selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, closest

Hope someone can advise. Having issues trying to remove a row once a link has been clicked.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Some Data</td><td><a href="#" class="remove-row>Remove Row</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some Data</td><td><a href="#" class="remove-row">Remove Row</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Now the JS

```
 $("a.remove-row").live('click', function(eve){
  eve.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/someaction/',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(msg){
    if(msg.error){
     alert(msg.error);
    }else{
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     alert(msg.success);
    }    
   }
  })
 });
```

This should be real simple buts its not removing the row. Just for kicks if I change it to something like

```
$('.remove-row').addClass('foo');
```

It will add foo to all table rows. So can understand why its not removing the closest row.

Any Ideas ?

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is `this` currently refers to the ajax object in your `success` callback, but it's an easy fix, use the `content` option like this:

```
 $("a.remove-row").live('click', function(eve){
  eve.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   context: this,                    //add this here!
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/someaction/',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(msg){
    if(msg.error){
     alert(msg.error);
    }else{
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     alert(msg.success);
    }    
   }
  })
 });
```

The `context` option dictates what `this` will be in the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback functions, since you want it to be the `.remove-row` you clicked on, use `this` as the option.

Comment: Nick - Minor correction. In the `success:` callback, `this` refers to the `xhr` object, not `window`. http://jsfiddle.net/WzeAh/ *This, of course, has no relevance with regard to your proposed solution.* +1

Comment: @patrick - Sorry, I'll clarify a bit more in the answer, it *behaves* like `window` for the current use, e.g. `$(this).find(selector)` works the same as if `$(this)` were `$(window)` or `$(document)`.

Comment: Nick - Unless I misunderstood your clarification, it doesn't seem (inside the callback) as though `$(this)` gives you the same behavior as `$(document)`, since doing a `.find()` returns `0` matches. http://jsfiddle.net/WzeAh/1/ EDIT: `$(window)` gives a `0` result as well.

Comment: @patrick - Updated, you're completely right, I had fubar'd my local jQuery install testing performance on this earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546825/is-there-such-thing-as-a-relative-jquery-selector/3546865#3546865 I didn't change back and completely screwed up my context on selectors....woops, thanks for pointing it out so this is more helpful to the next guy.

Answer (score 2):

Nick's answer should work, but you can do this too, I don't know which one is better, probably Nick's one, but it may help anyway...

```
$("a.remove-row").live('click', function(eve){
  var row = this;
  eve.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/someaction/',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(msg){
    if(msg.error){
     alert(msg.error);
    }else{
     $(row).closest('tr').remove();
     alert(msg.success);
    }    
   }
  })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unclosed attribute `class="remove-row` at the first row.

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9kpA/)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to do the remove/hide before hand?

like this :

```
$("a.remove-row").live('click', function(eve){
      $(this).hide();
      <The rest of your code logic>
         ......
```